# Function Parameters for LabVIEW DLL

Tags: c#, dll, dllimport, labview

I am trying to call a function from a DLL generated in LabVIEW. I thought this was going to be far more straightforward than it is turning out to be. The function is described below:

```
void __cdecl Device_Init(char DevName[]);
```

So in my C# code I am trying the following:

```
[DllImport(@"Device.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern void Device_Init(StringBuilder name);
```

I call this in my application by simply using the following:

```
StringBuilder devName = new StringBuilder(DeviceName);
Device_Init(devName);
```

Rather than getting any initialization on my device, I see a LabVIEW vi window pop up that has a title akin to a different method within the dll (i.e. AF1_GetPressure.vi). The application then hangs with this LabVIEW window popped up and I have to exit the debugging session.

I guess my question is how my function signature might be erroneous... I used StringBuilder as I found an example on the NI website that seemed to indicate that LabVIEW requires this variable type to better ascertain the number of characters in the array. http://www.ni.com/example/31050/en/

I have tried all kinds of different combinations of parameter types but I simply can't seem to get this to work. If I try calling the dll from C++ then I can get things to work. Although, oddly, I had to dynamically load the dll in C++ because I was getting a dll initialization failure when I tried to load it with the application.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I happen to have Labview 2012 (with ApplicationBuilder) and VS2010, so I might be able to try this out, but I've never made a DLL with Labview. Can you briefly outline the process you followed, or link to a VI?

Comment: Ok... So here is the weird part... I was inspired by @Steve to call the supplied LabVIEW DLL from a stripped down application. So I created a quick Windows Form application and called my DLL. Miraculously, this worked! I went back to my application framework and tried to call the DLL from the constructor of my main form after component initialization and again I had success. I then tried calling the DLL from the On_Load event of my main form and that is when the application failed to load the DLL. So, the question is, what happens btw form construction and loading that causes the failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to build a DLL with LabView 2012, and import it into a .NET 4.0 console application, call the function, and receive a result. Here is a screenshot of the VI:

[image: LabView VI]

And here is the import statement in C#:

```
[DllImport(@"SharedLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)] 
private static extern int StringLength(string str);
```

I would recommend trying something very simple like this and see if you can get it working.

I should note that I tried passing my parameter as a `StringBuilder` object and that worked as well - and I didn't expect it to!

Also, I recommend posting this question on the LabView forums. I was always able to get a very quick response there, and I think with LabView, you're likely to get a better response there than StackOverflow.

As requested, here are the contents of the .h file generated by LabView:

```
#include "extcode.h"
#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(1)

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/*!
 * StringLength
 */
int32_t __cdecl StringLength(char String[]);

long __cdecl LVDLLStatus(char *errStr, int errStrLen, void *module);

#ifdef __cplusplus
} // extern "C"
#endif

#pragma pack(pop)
```

Comment: Hi Steve. Thanks for the response. I am trying to follow up on the NI site as well. Would you please be so kind as to post the exported function declaration in the header file?

Comment: I've added it to my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I just discovered that when I call the LabVIEW dll from the vendor via C++ then I will get everything to work correctly but I see a memory exception thrown after one of the NI dlls is loaded: 'TestElveFlow.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\nimercu.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
First-chance exception at 0x7c812afb in TestElveFlow.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: LVExcept at memory location 0x023bc870..

Comment: On the C# side of things, the application hangs on the module load where this exception is thrown. I'm looping back with the NI community but no one has a response yet.

Comment: Not sure about that... The PDB file is used for symbolic debugging. My guess is that it's trying to find it to help you debug the exception but can't. I don't think I'll be of any more help unfortunately. I wish you good luck! You might want to unaccept my answer since you're still having your problem (or not, I like the rep :)

Comment: I'm not concerned about the PDB file but more about the "LVExcept at memory location 0x023bc870" that comes immediately after that DLL is loaded. I'm wondering if calling the DLL from a managed environment and then encountering this memory error is the root of my problems...